# Push Notification on Azure Environment

Tags: android, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on windows azure from last 6 months ,now i need to work on push notification on  android and Iphone mobile devices.
I have done all the code on local system for both devices and working fine.
but while I have deployed it on azure development server it showing me exception on sending notification on iphone i.e .p12 certificate not found  or certificate is null.
when code in web role ,it is working fine on local system  and sending all the notification on both GCM and ANPS.
I have goggled a lot and it results me that put the notification code on worker role  and I do the same  but it is showing error during deploying  services.
in worker role i have accessing .p12 certificate via Environment variables (roleroot) that is also working fine on local system.as doing this my all the supporting DLL's are copied to worker role and make package size bulky..

Please any one help me out.

Comment: So GCM is working for you, and ANPS (I assume windows thing?) is working for you. And IPhones isnt?

Comment: Thanks for quick response .yes GCM is working fine on azure development server and while  i send push notification on Iphone  error log show me that .P12  not found or null

Comment: Should post this under IPhone/Ios development then and not android imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, obviously you need to upload that certificate too.

Comment: Yes I have uploaded it on server but no luck

Comment: and last but not least you also need to define that certificate in ServiceDefinition and ServiceConfiguration files - name and fingerprint.

Comment: Yes! that is i need to know to how to define the .p12 certificate  in the same, even i have used  ssl certificate on these.Can you tell me that the whole code will be same as the ssl certificate code

Comment: I have used HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\"); in Web role and certificate is accessing in web role without uploading certificate on azure server. and its working fine in push notification on Iphones and android.